# Create hana tuple with unmovable / noncopyable types

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I'm trying to wrap my head around the great boost::hana and try to figure out how to translate some old school tuple code.

Maybe it's a bit special but I have types that are neither copyable nor moveable and want to pack them in a container. Think policy design ...

I guess I'm just not getting how to create a hana tuple in the value world. The way I'm trying doesn't work because `make<Tuple>(CompT{}...)` needs types that are either copyable or at least moveable.

So most likely this is just not the way to do it. Or is this a limitation of hana?

Thanks!

```cpp
struct NonMoveable
{
    NonMoveable() = default;
    NonMoveable(const NonMoveable& other) = delete;

    int val;
};

struct Simple { int val; };

template <typename ...CompT>
struct OldSchoolContainer
{
    template <int I>
    auto& getComponent()
    {
        return std::get<I>(components);
    }

    std::tuple<CompT...> components;
};

template <typename ...CompT>
struct HanaContainer
{
    using Args_t = decltype(make<Tuple>(CompT{}...));

    template <int I>
    auto& getComponent()
    {
        return components[int_<I>];
    }

    Args_t components;
};

int main()
{
    OldSchoolContainer<Simple> simpleOsc;
    static_assert(std::is_same<Simple&, decltype(simpleOsc.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");

    HanaContainer<Simple> simpleHanaC;
    static_assert(std::is_same<Simple&, decltype(simpleHanaC.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");


    OldSchoolContainer<NonMoveable> nonmoveableOsc;
    static_assert(std::is_same<NonMoveable&, decltype(nonmoveableOsc.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");

    // !!! this does not compile because hana's tuple closure needs to either move or copy
    HanaContainer<NonMoveable> nonmoveableHanaC;
    static_assert(std::is_same<NonMoveable&, decltype(nonmoveableHanaC.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hana::_tuple<...>` type almost exactly as `std::tuple`. 
Hence, the following works:

```
#include <boost/hana/integral_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


struct NonMoveable
{
    NonMoveable() = default;
    NonMoveable(const NonMoveable& other) = delete;

    int val;
};

struct Simple { int val; };

template <typename ...CompT>
struct HanaContainer
{
    template <int I>
    auto& getComponent()
    {
        return components[hana::int_<I>];
    }

    hana::_tuple<CompT...> components;
};

int main()
{
    HanaContainer<Simple> simpleHanaC;
    static_assert(std::is_same<Simple&, decltype(simpleHanaC.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");

    HanaContainer<NonMoveable> nonmoveableHanaC;
    static_assert(std::is_same<NonMoveable&, decltype(nonmoveableHanaC.getComponent<0>())>::value, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was easy :-) Thank you very much Louis! That was the missing link. Maybe it would be worth to add a section to your great documentation. When you know it it's easy to find in the examples but it's easy to miss since in the docs everything is auto and only the factory functions are used. Great work really!

Comment: No problem! I'm preparing a rather large update for the library following the formal Boost review, and this will be documented better.